# Azure DevOps - Python and Powershell tasks added to build pipeline are not publishing their progress

Tags: python, powershell, azure-devops, jmeter

I am trying to run JMeter tests through DevOps build pipeline, this is done with the help of two tasks. One python tasks to update user.profile and one powershell task that invokes a powershell script to start JMeter tests using command line parameters.

However, when i run the build pipeline the tasks are getting executed in the background but i cannot see the progress or the task in the execution summary. Its like those two tasks are not at all there.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank You
[BuildPipleline_Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ueTP.png)

Comment: There are a number of potential problems: can you provide examples for your tasks, setup, permissions, etc., to help readers recreate the issue?

Comment: Which server are you using? TFS? Or Azure devops? Does this issue pipeline also un-viewable for other users? I mean they also saw task log disappear? This can help to locate is it caused by permission or other?

Comment: I am using Azure DevOps. Its not appearing for everyone who has rights to the agent pool.

Comment: This has pipeline has two tasks, Step 1: Python task to run a python script that updates a file. Step 2: A Powershell Task to run a powershell script that start JMeter tests on a JMeter agent. The user has access to Agent Pool and permission to execute the tasks in the agent. I can manually go into the agent and see that the tasks are getting executed. i.e. the file is updated by the python task, jmeter tests are invoked by powershell task.

Comment: @Novoicedev, May I know which region your organization is located in? Also, is it affect all pipelines? Or only this one abnormal? I would want these message to marrow down some issue from our backend. In addition, did you ever try re-run this pipeline to see whether it still exists?